# Regex quantifier error

Tags: regex, perl, text, replace, sed

I am trying to replace all the occurrences of

```
**********
```

in a large text file with

```
 (space)nan(space)
```

(space character). The graphical text editor cannot be used because the size of the text file is too large. Before readily replacing this I also want to find how many occurrences of "**********" occurs in my file. What is the better way to do this?

I tried this(which readily replaces the string), but gets some error:

```
perl -i.bak -p -e 's{**********}{ nan }g' RayMet_140529.ray_paths
```

Error:

```
Quantifier follows nothing in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/* <-- HERE *********/ at -e line 1.
```

Looking forward for some help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`*` is  a special character in regex patterns. You must escape it in order to match a literal `*` character. You can also use a repetition quantifier `{10}` to avoid having to repeat the character ten times.

```
perl -i.bak -p -e 's/\*{10}/ nan /g' RayMet_140529.ray_paths
```